# Getting so high average response time in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am testing a scenario with 400 threads. Although I am almost getting no errors, I have very high average response. What can bring about this problem? Seems like server gives no time-out but gives response so late. I've addded the **summary report**. It is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This table doesn't tell the full story, if response time seems "so high" to you - this is definitely the [bottleneck](https://qa-platforms.com/detecting-bottlenecks-performance-testing/) and you can report it already.

What you can do to localize the problem is:

1. Consider using a longer [ramp-up period](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-the-ultimate-guide), i.e. start with 1 user and add 1 more user every 5 seconds (adjust these numbers according to your scenario) so you would have arrival phase, the "plateau" and the load decrease phase. This approach will allow you to correlate increasing load and increasing response time by looking at [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) and [Response Times Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime/) charts. This way you will be able to state that:

   - response time remains the same up to X concurrent users
   - after X concurrent users it starts growing so throughput is going down
   - after Z concurrent users response time exceeds acceptable threshold
2. It would also be good to see CPU, RAM, etc. usage on the server side as increased response time might be due to lack of resources, you can use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) for this
3. Inspect your server configuration as you might need to tune it for high loads (same applies to JMeter, make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html))
4. Use a [profiler tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) on server side during the next test execution, it will show you the slowest places in your application code